# I get "ValueError: shapes **** and **** not aligned: ** (dim *) != ** (dim 0)" only when paralleling the process and calling it from a class

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing, python-multithreading, joblib

This problem only triggers when I am distributing the process on multiple cores using joblib. I can't share my exact code, but I was able to reproduce in this simplest meaningless form:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model
from joblib import Parallel, delayed

X = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 100))
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10000, 1), columns=['response'])

class A():
    def __init__(self, model_type):
        self.model_type = model_type

    def proc(self, X, y):
        if self.model_type == 'linear':
            reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
        train_results = []
        train_results = Parallel(n_jobs=4, backend="threading")(delayed(train)(X[range(i+1)], y, reg) for i in X.columns)
        return train_results

def train(X, y, reg):
    model = reg.fit(X, y)
    return model.predict(X)

results = A('linear').proc(X, y)
```

If I run the last command, I will get the following error:

```
ValueError: shapes (10000,27) and (28,1) not aligned: 27 (dim 1) != 28 (dim 0)
```

Although the shapes (10000,27) and (28,1) may be different in every run, However, if I set n_jobs to 1, it works fine. Also if I was only using 1 feature/variable/column in every iteration, it works fine (i.e X[i] instead of X[range(i+1)])

I thought it could be the class method, so I tried to run it without using the class method, I got the same error when using n_jobs > 1. Can anyone help? I am using python 2.7 with spyder on a windows machine.